# Run zend framework demos in local xampp

Tags: zend-framework

I have decided to begin with zend framework. I have installed it under xampp running on windows and I'm trying to runs the demos (Especially ZendFramework-1.11.11\demos\Zend\Pdf)

but I get the message : `USAGE: php demo.php []`

no pdf file is genarated, but when I try a simple zend function like `echo 'Zend Framework version ' . Zend_Version::VERSION;` I get the right zend version. ==> It means that my zend is properly installed.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

`USAGE: php demo.php` means that this example should be launched from command line.

To do this you should have `path/to/php.exe` in `PATH` environment variable.

```
php C:\ZendFramework-1.11.11\demos\Zend\Pdf\demo.php [your args]
```